# Why Cypress throw this error: Step implementation missing for...(even when there is implemented step def.)

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor, e2e

I am using Cypress version `10.9.0` for `e2e` testing. Of course, there are more step defs but it stops at the first `then` step as it can be seen from the SS image.

```js
When('I enter an invalid username on the login page', () => {
    cy.get('#username').type('portal').invoke('removeAttr', 'value').click({ force: true }, { timeout: 30000 })
    cy.get('#password').type('SwY66bc3VZLUFR9')
    cy.get('[type="submit"]').click()
})
 
Then('an error message is displayed with the text Invalid username/password', () => {
    cy.get(".invalid.text-left").should('contain.text', 'Invalid username/password')
})
```

**Cypress GUI error**

[image: Cypress GUI error]

**DOM element**

[image: DOM element]

Comment: Are you using the cypress-cucumber-preprocessor? https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor If so, can you share `.feature` file as well?

Comment: Hi @ManuelAbascal, yes I am using that cypress-cucumber-preprocessor. I have attached `.feature` file. 

```Feature: Login

 Scenario: #1 Test Invalid Username / Invalid Password / Empty Username / Valid Username and Empty Password
  Given I am at the portal login page
  When I enter an invalid username on the login page
  Then an error message is displayed with the text Invalid username/password
  When I enter an invalid password on the login page
  Then an error message is displayed with the text Invalid username/password```

Comment: It's coming from cucumber then, you gotta make sure that the description is matching in both `.feature` & `.spec` files

Answer (score 2):

The error says cannot find `#username` but clearly it is present, so you may have a `shadowroot` in the DOM above the `<input>`.

If so, add a configuration to allow searching within, in `cypress.config.js`

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:1234'
  },
  includeShadowDom: true,
})
```

If you don't see `shadowroot`, look for an `<iframe>` element.
Handling an iframe is best done with [Cypress iframe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-iframe)

Comment: Hi @jasonScaggs After doing what you have said here, now I am getting this error: 
```then{}, function(){}
Error
Step implementation missing for: an error message is displayed with the text Invalid username/password```